# Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) dispatch source flags

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I recently switched from using [kqueue](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&format=html) to [GCD dispatch sources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1385630-dispatch_source_create) to monitor file changes. This has worked out well and resulted in a much simpler API. I documented my switch [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825044413/http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/10/10/handling-filesystem-events-with-gcd.html). The only issue I have is that now I cannot access the flags on the event that I was able to in kqueue. For example with kqueue I was able to check if the file was deleted, renamed, or it's attributes were changed with the following:

```
struct kevent event;

...

if(event.flag & EV_DELETE)
{
    printf("File was deleted\n");
}
```

Is this API not available with GCD or do I need to set up dispatch sources up for each flag I would like to listen to. Or is it best to use kqueue since it provides greater visibility to the event that has occurred.

Comment: I didn't actually read your question, but I thumbed it up so your reputation can be 1337. Ok I'll read it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW10). I had first looked in the [GCD Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch?language=objc) but without luck. The relevant line from the guide was

> For a descriptor dispatch source that monitors file system activity, this function returns a constant indicating the type of event that occurred. For a list of constants, see the dispatch_source_vnode_flags_t enumerated type.

Here is an example of how you can use it.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
int fildes = open("path/to/some/file", O_EVTONLY);
__block dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE,fildes, 
                                                  DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE | DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE | DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND | DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB | DISPATCH_VNODE_LINK | DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME | DISPATCH_VNODE_REVOKE,
                                                  queue);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, ^
{
    unsigned long flags = dispatch_source_get_mask(source);
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_LINK)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_LINK\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME\n");
    if(flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_REVOKE)
        printf("DISPATCH_VNODE_REVOKE\n");
});
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(source, ^(void) 
{
    close(fildes);
});
dispatch_resume(source);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's amazing. I used the one on your [blog post](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/10/13/Monitoring-Files-With-GCD-Being-Edited-With-A-Text-Editor.html). However, you should correct the line 17 from `[blockSelf watchStyleSheet:path];` to `[blockSelf watchConfigFile:path];`.

Comment: there is no point for `source` to be `__block` as it is never assigned to

Comment: also it should be `dispatch_source_get_data` instead of `dispatch_source_get_mask`. The glory of using someone else's code without actually understanding it...

Answer (score 5):

You may change *dispatch_source_get_mask(source)* to *dispatch_source_get_data(source)*, as dispatch_source_get_mask(source) returns all the flags you passed in the creation of the handler instead of the event generated.