# How to monitor a folder for new files in swift?

Tags: macos, swift

How would I monitor a folder for new files in swift, without polling (which is very inefficient)? I've heard of APIs such as kqueue and FSEvents - but I'm not sure it's possible to implement them in swift?

Comment: `FSEventStreamCreate` is missing from Swift, not allowing a pure Swift implementation. However, you could make an Obj-C wrapper class and manipulate that with Swift. I had to do similar with CommonCrypto for hashing.

Comment: Note: Here's an old discussion about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720246/monitoring-a-directory-in-cocoa-cocoa-touch

Comment: I see a Swift version of FSEventStreamCreate which I'm battling to use (due to total lack of Swift knowledge...) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSEventStreamCreate

Comment: I found http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/06/27/developing-a-filesystemwatcher-for-os-x-by-using-fsevents-with-swift-2/ which looks promising but unfortunately doesn't cope well with memory. I just need to know _which_ file has been added but there doesn't seem to be a simple solution.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/gurinderhans/SwiftFSWatcher . It even allows  creating multiple `monitors` for different places.

Answer (score 17):

GCD seems to be the way to go. `NSFilePresenter` classes doesn't work properly. They're buggy, broken, and Apple is haven't willing to fix them for last 4 years. Likely to be deprecated.

Here's a very nice posting which describes essentials of this technique.

["Handling Filesystem Events with GCD"](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/10/10/handling-filesystem-events-with-gcd.html), by *David Hamrick*.

Sample code cited from the website. I translated his C code into Swift.

```
    let fildes = open("/path/to/config.plist", O_RDONLY)

    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    let source = dispatch_source_create(
        DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE,
        UInt(fildes),
        DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE | DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE | DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND | DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB | DISPATCH_VNODE_LINK | DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME | DISPATCH_VNODE_REVOKE,
        queue)

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source,
        {
            //Reload the config file
        })

    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(source,
        {
            //Handle the cancel
        })

    dispatch_resume(source);

    ...

        // sometime later
        dispatch_source_cancel(source);
```

For reference, here're another QAs posted by the author:

- [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) dispatch source flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748725/grand-central-dispatch-gcd-dispatch-source-flags/7748919#7748919)
- [Monitoring a directory in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720246/monitoring-a-directory-in-cocoa-cocoa-touch)

---

If you're interested in watching directories, here's another posting which describes it.

["Monitoring a Folder with GCD"](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/08/monitoring-a-folder-with-gcd/) on *Cocoanetics*. (unfortunately, I couldn't find the author's name. I am sorry for lacking attribution)

The only noticeable difference is getting a file-descriptor. This makes event-notification-only file descriptor for a directory.

```
_fileDescriptor = open(path.fileSystemRepresentation(), O_EVTONLY)
```

---

### Update

Previously I claimed `FSEvents` API is not working, but I was wrong. The API is working very well, and if you're interested in watching on deep file tree, than it can be better then GCD by its simplicity.

Anyway, FSEvents cannot be used in pure Swift programs. Because it requires passing of C callback function, and Swift does not support it currently (Xcode 6.1.1). Then I had to fallback to Objective-C and wrap it again.

Also, any of this kind API is all fully asynchronous. That means actual file system state can be different at the time you are receiving the notifications. Then precise or accurate notification is not really helpful, and useful only for marking a dirty flag.

### Update 2

I finally ended up with writing a wrapper around `FSEvents` for Swift.
Here's my work, and I hope this to be helpful.

- https://github.com/eonil/FileSystemEvents

Comment: Nice. I tried to 'listen' to a folder being written to once, but gave up because I couldn't get `FSEvents` to work properly. I was waiting for very large image files to be written by a camera driver, and never quite got to be notified at the right moment when the file was 'ready' to be opened, ended with black images, etc. Also, I saw some inconsistency in the messages being broadcast and had a hard time interpreting them. Perhaps I didn't understand the docs properly and didn't come across good sample code. WILL definitely try GCD.

Comment: Thanks. I just used your Framework by cloning directly from GitHub, and followed your video and Built! Worked first time. So, now I just need to learn some Swift to use it! :-)

Comment: Hey @Eonil do you know how can I detect when a file is updated/modified? I saw your approximation and I have tried few more that i have found but none fires when the file is updated.

Comment: `NSFilePresenter` is not a class, it's a protocol. It has no functionality on its own. It's typically used with a `NSFileCoordinator` and this class is not for monitoring directories but for coordinating read/write I/O operations on file systems within a single process as well as across process boundaries and that works perfectly using `NSFileCoordinator`.

Answer (score 15):

I adapted Stanislav Smida's code to make it work with Xcode 8 and Swift 3

```
class DirectoryObserver {

    private let fileDescriptor: CInt
    private let source: DispatchSourceProtocol

    deinit {

      self.source.cancel()
      close(fileDescriptor)
    }

    init(URL: URL, block: @escaping ()->Void) {

      self.fileDescriptor = open(URL.path, O_EVTONLY)
      self.source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: self.fileDescriptor, eventMask: .all, queue: DispatchQueue.global())
      self.source.setEventHandler { 
          block()
      }
      self.source.resume()
  }

}
```

Comment: Tested with Swift 4.2 and still works great. Thank You!

Comment: 2021 year. Code works. Great file monitor! looks exactly only one directory without subdirectories. Just the think that I searched for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: 2023, Xcode 14.2, Swift 5.7 works!

Comment: As this is referring to @StanislavSmida, it is worth mentioning that he advised to capture `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to use Apple's DirectoryMonitor.swift
https://github.com/Lax/Learn-iOS-Swift-by-Examples/blob/master/Lister/ListerKit/DirectoryMonitor.swift

```
var dm = DirectoryMonitor(URL: AppDelegate.applicationDocumentsDirectory)
dm.delegate = self
dm.startMonitoring()
```

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Yes, apple has removed this link(

Comment: Swift 3 version mirrored at: https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/blob/master/ListerforwatchOSiOSandOSX/Swift/ListerKit/DirectoryMonitor.swift

Comment: 2024: https://github.com/apple/swift-docc/blob/release/5.9.1/Sources/SwiftDocCUtilities/Utility/DirectoryMonitor.swift

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 Version for Directory Monitor, with GCD, original from [Apple](https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/ListerforwatchOSiOSandOSX/Swift/ListerKit)

```
import Foundation

/// A protocol that allows delegates of `DirectoryMonitor` to respond to changes in a directory.
protocol DirectoryMonitorDelegate: class {
    func directoryMonitorDidObserveChange(directoryMonitor: DirectoryMonitor)
}

class DirectoryMonitor {
    // MARK: Properties

    /// The `DirectoryMonitor`'s delegate who is responsible for responding to `DirectoryMonitor` updates.
    weak var delegate: DirectoryMonitorDelegate?

    /// A file descriptor for the monitored directory.
    var monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor: CInt = -1

    /// A dispatch queue used for sending file changes in the directory.
    let directoryMonitorQueue =  DispatchQueue(label: "directorymonitor", attributes: .concurrent)

    /// A dispatch source to monitor a file descriptor created from the directory.
    var directoryMonitorSource: DispatchSource?

    /// URL for the directory being monitored.
    var url: URL

    // MARK: Initializers
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    // MARK: Monitoring

    func startMonitoring() {
        // Listen for changes to the directory (if we are not already).
        if directoryMonitorSource == nil && monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor == -1 {
            // Open the directory referenced by URL for monitoring only.
            monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor = open((url as NSURL).fileSystemRepresentation, O_EVTONLY)

            // Define a dispatch source monitoring the directory for additions, deletions, and renamings.
            directoryMonitorSource = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor, eventMask: DispatchSource.FileSystemEvent.write, queue: directoryMonitorQueue) as? DispatchSource

            // Define the block to call when a file change is detected.
            directoryMonitorSource?.setEventHandler{
                // Call out to the `DirectoryMonitorDelegate` so that it can react appropriately to the change.
                self.delegate?.directoryMonitorDidObserveChange(directoryMonitor: self)
            }

            // Define a cancel handler to ensure the directory is closed when the source is cancelled.
            directoryMonitorSource?.setCancelHandler{
                close(self.monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor)

                self.monitoredDirectoryFileDescriptor = -1

                self.directoryMonitorSource = nil
            }

            // Start monitoring the directory via the source.
            directoryMonitorSource?.resume()
        }
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        // Stop listening for changes to the directory, if the source has been created.
        if directoryMonitorSource != nil {
            // Stop monitoring the directory via the source.
            directoryMonitorSource?.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to write `(url as NSURL).fileSystemRepresentation`? I tried url.path() and it works.

Answer (score 2):

[SKQueue](https://github.com/daniel-pedersen/SKQueue) is a Swift wrapper around kqueue. Here is sample code that watches a directory and notifies of write events.

```
class SomeClass: SKQueueDelegate {
  func receivedNotification(_ notification: SKQueueNotification, path: String, queue: SKQueue) {
    print("\(notification.toStrings().map { $0.rawValue }) @ \(path)")
  }
}

if let queue = SKQueue() {
  let delegate = SomeClass()

  queue.delegate = delegate
  queue.addPath("/some/file/or/directory")
  queue.addPath("/some/other/file/or/directory")
}
```

Comment: the problem is: how to receive a list of files added to the monitored directory.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to go with these few lines. So far seems to work.

```
class DirectoryObserver {

    deinit {

        dispatch_source_cancel(source)
        close(fileDescriptor)
    }

    init(URL: NSURL, block: dispatch_block_t) {

        fileDescriptor = open(URL.path!, O_EVTONLY)
        source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE, UInt(fileDescriptor), DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE, dispatch_queue_create(nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT))
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block) })
        dispatch_resume(source)
    }

    //

    private let fileDescriptor: CInt
    private let source: dispatch_source_t
}
```

Be sure to not get into retain cycle. If you are going to use owner of this instance in block, do it safely. For example:

```
self.directoryObserver = DirectoryObserver(URL: URL, block: { [weak self] in

    self?.doSomething()
})
```

Comment: Great code. Here is an example monitoring the desktop: let theURL = NSURL("~/Desktop/".stringByExpandingTildeInPath)

Comment: Your code only works when files are added or deleted. Not file changes. Great anyways. I need to monitor file changes so ill keep looking.

Comment: FSEvent seems to be what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method I've found that I'm currently using is this wonderful library: https://github.com/eonist/FileWatcher

[From README](https://github.com/eonist/FileWatcher/blob/master/README.md)

#### Installation:

- CocoaPods `pod "FileWatcher"`
- Carthage `github "eonist/FileWatcher" "master"`
- Manual Open `FileWatcherExample.xcodeproj`

```swift
let filewatcher = FileWatcher([NSString(string: "~/Desktop").expandingTildeInPath])

filewatcher.callback = { event in
  print("Something happened here: " + event.path)
}

filewatcher.start() // start monitoring
```

Comment: but is it efficient?

Comment: Works great for me. No performance hiccups. What's your use case?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a problem that is not mentioned in any of the answers. As my app is using a UIDocumentBrowserViewController (i.e. Apple's own Files app) to manage its documents, I have no control over my users' habits. I was using [SKQueue](https://github.com/daniel-pedersen/SKQueue) to monitor all files in order to keep metadata in sync, and at a certain point the app started crashing.

As it turns out, there is an upper limit of 256 file descriptors that can be open by an app simultaneously, even just for monitoring. I ended up combining SKQueue and Apple's Directory Monitor (reference to which you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035069/10327858) of the current thread) to create a class I named [SFSMonitor](https://github.com/ClassicalDude/SFSMonitor), which monitors a whole queue of files or directories by using Dispatch Sources.

I detailed my findings and the practices I now use in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62166898/10327858).

Comment: Does it monitor subdirectories?

Comment: Every directory and subdirectory is monitored as an individual entity. Let's say you copy a subdirectory into a monitored directory: you'll be notified of that change, but you will not know about anything that happens within that subdirectory. You will have to check what was added, and when you realize it is a subdirectory, add it to your watched list. In other words - watching is not recursive, and a subdirectory is just another entry, as far as the original directory is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You could add UKKQueue to your project. See http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm it's easy to use. UKKQueue is written in Objective C, but you can use it from swift

Comment: Note that UKKQueue has been claimed superseded by https://github.com/bdkjones/VDKQueue in 2012, itself also claimed to be superseded by GCD in 2011 (https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/l6j3g/using_kqueue_in_cocoa/c2q74yy)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your application needs, you may be able to use a simple solution.

I actually used kqueue in a production product; I wasn't crazy with the performance but it worked, so I didn't think too much of it till I found a nice little trick that worked even better for my needs, plus, it used less resources which can be important for performance intensive programs.

What you can do, again, if your project permits, is that every time you switch to your application, you can just check the folder as part of your logic, instead of having to periodically check the folder using kqueue. This works and uses far less resources.

Comment: I think Atom.io does this when it asserts if a file has been pushed via git. Its totally annoying to have to switch back and forth between apps to see the change. This is an UI/UX anti-pattern to me.